# Yii GridView returns a blank screen?

Tags: database, orm, grid, yii

Yii GridView returns a blank screen, when a dataProvider return a many models;
IMAGES BROWSER

[image]

Comment: try to var_dump($dataProvider->getData()) and check if you are getting any result.

Comment: First comes the uploading, then after a while a blank screen returns vor_dump shows nothing

Comment: Can you please show your code here . I mean the controller and the model script

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 48 bytes) in /.../yii/framework/db/CDbCommand.php on line 516 Apache Logs

Answer (score 0):

This is Apache Fatal error: **Allowed memory size of**... , i decided with the help of

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```